# Merging two lists lazily in Python

Tags: python, list, collections, merge, lazy-evaluation

I have two virtual list proxies which dynamically hits into a database when a position or a range of position are requested to the list. That means for example:

```
lazy_list[0]
```

will do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM=0
```

or `lazy_list[1:10]` something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROWNUM>0 AND ROWNUM<11
```

or `len(lazy_list)` something like:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

That means that merging two of two of these lists would be expensive using the default `python` natural ways of merging lists as it would hit the database even when is not necesarily needed.

If I were to merge two list with the similar behavior into an iterable I could use `itertools.chain` to iterate through both chained lists lazily.

I was wondering If there exists something similar for building lazy lists in python. For example let say that we have two lazy lists `lazy_list1` and `lazy_list2`, for the following operations the merged lazy list would hit and calculate the results automatically as follows:

1. `len(merged_list) = len(lazy_list1) + len(lazy_list2)`
2. If `len(lazy_list1) = 4` and `len(lazy_list2) = 5`,

   `merged_list[1:7] = lazy_list1[1:4] + lazy_list2[0:4]`

Comment: How are `lazy_list1` and `lazy_list2` created?

Comment: Have a look at Django's [QuerySet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L45) implementation, they allow you to do these things lazily.

Comment: Is not important how `lazy_list1` and `lazy_list2` are created, the important thing is that is expensive to do the natural merging using the default python operator since this solution will iterate through both lists even when data in those lists are not needed right away.


About the Django solution, is it actually in Django where I am trying to solve the problem, which is the abstraction of `QuerySets` with other lists types into a single list.


I want to know if there exists any third-party solution or in the API that allows to merge two lists lazily